# how to use = and >= in for and while loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to python and I am try to understand why the following breaks and how to do this better:

```
x = [5,5,5,5,6,7,87,8,9,10]
for i in range(len(x)):
    while i == 5:
        print('5')
    else:
        print('no')
```

-This code runs forever producing 5's

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    while i = 5:
        print('5')
    else:
        print('no')
```

-This breaks

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    while i => 5:
        print('5')
    else:
        print('no')
```

-This breaks

How do I program a simple loop to print '5' if the value of i is 5 and print 'no' in the other instances? how do I use signs like = and >= in loops? Python seems not to recognize them

Comment: Do you know what `while` means? You probably are looking for an `if`.

Comment: It’s `==` for equality comparisons, and `>=` for greater or equals. The order matters here.

Comment: *"This breaks"* is not an appropriate problem description. In this case it is simple to see that you are messing up on basic syntax, but for the future you should always be as precise as possible when writing questions and include all error messages you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [5,5,5,5,6,7,87,8,9,10]
for c in x:
    if c == 5:
        print('5')
    else:
        print('no')
```

`while i==5` is always `True` because the value of `i` never changes inside the body of the `for` loop.